# angular 2 keep getting a UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.0

Tags: angular, npm

I am using angular cli for my angular 2 project, but I keep running into

`UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.0`

when I do npm install.  Can someone help me with this?  When I type `npm list typescript` it says 1.8 is installed even though the package.json lists `"typescript": "^2.0.0"`

Comment: Have you tried to update it?

Comment: yeah i tried to do `npm install typescript@2.0.0` but the version doesn't change when i do `npm list typescript` :(  am i doing it wrong?

Comment: That's fine. Try to uninstall old version,then reinstall new one. Or run `npm update typescript`

Comment: thanks i will try this.  just lost internet connection on my laptop ... :(

Comment: ok i just did it, and it still says UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY :(

Comment: looks like you are not the only one: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1737

Comment: great i guess i will wait lol thanks

Comment: try to install typescript@beta, maybe this will work. (ts 2.0 isn't released yet)